# Arranging Elements from Top to Bottom with horizontal scrollview

Tags: react-native, user-interface, jsx

i need to display 4 data with vertical and put in to horizontal scrollview with react-native.

For example i need display like this https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/

This is the current code i have tried. Thank you

```
 <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                >
                  <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                      flexWrap:"wrap"
                    }}
                    numColumns={item.options.length / 4}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={item.options}
                    renderItem={itemLabel => this.renderFilterLabel(itemLabel)}
                  />
                </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution maybe help you :)

```js
render() {
  let arrayLength =Math.round(parseInt(this.state.data.length / 4))
  let columnsNumber = arrayLength % 4 === 0 ? arrayLength : arrayLength+1
  return (

    <View>
      <ScrollView
          horizontal={true}
        >
          <FlatList
            numColumns={columnsNumber}
            data={this.state.date}
            renderItem={(itemLabel) => this._renderItems(itemLabel)}
          />
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

you can see it here:

[image]

Comment: wow very good solution and also 1 more question how to make the data become vertical display

Comment: did you mean all of your data become vertical Scroll? if I right understood you just need FlatList, by default FlatList render data vertically. :)

Comment: nope is not about the scroll. now you have done the horizontal scrollview and display data 4 column, but the data still render display from left to right. I need make it become top to bottom. For example, 1 2 3 4 and 5 will be beside of 1 not 4.so that the data need to vertical display. thank you